# Can't detect GPU ATI temperature sensor

Tags: 12.04, gpu, temperature, sensors

I've an ATi Mobility HD4650 and I'd like to detect its sensor.

I've installed `lm-sensors`, `xsensors` and the Hardware Sensors Indicator, but I can't find my GPU sensor.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Also, if I use the `aticonfig --od-gettemperature` command, I get this error:

> ERROR - Get temperature failed for the Default Adapter - ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

Comment: Try removing the proprietary video drivers.  The open source ones generally make the sensor available.

Comment: I'll try that, I'm using the fglrx, not the post release one.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the reading using `aticonfig --odgt`.